# are defaultdict(set) operations thread safe in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, defaultdict

I am pretty naive to python, and in the situation where I have to deal with multi-threading in my production code. cut-pasting some part of code, which replicates the similar functionality below:

```
class DataProcessor(object):
def __init__(self, config: DataProcessorConfig) -> None:
    self.config = config
    self.lock = defaultdict(set)
    self.function_thread_lock = threading.Lock()
    self.config_singleton = ConfigSingleton.create_instance()

def process_data(self, data_record: Dict[str, str]) -> None:
    self._logger.debug(f"record: {data_record}")
try:
    self.acquire_locks(data_record)
    self.process_record(data_record)
finally:
    self.release_locks(data_record)

def release_locks(self, data_record: Dict[str, str]) -> None:
    with self.function_thread_lock:
        for obj in self.config_singleton.get_ids(parameter):
            id_value = obj.get_id_value(data_record)
            if id_value:
                self.lock[obj.id_key].remove(obj.get_id_value(data_record))
                
def acquire_locks(self, data_record: Dict[str, str], threshold: int = 3) -> None:
    for obj in self._config_singleton.get_ids(parameter):
        try_count = 1
        id_value = obj.get_id_value(data_record)
        if id_value:
            while try_count <= threshold:
                try:
                    self.function_thread_lock.acquire()
                    if id_value not in self.lock[id_obj.id_key]:
                        self.lock[id_obj.id_key].add(id_value)
                        break
                finally:
                    self.function_thread_lock.release()
                sleep_amount = 2**try_count
                time.sleep(sleep_amount)
                try_count += 1
            else:
                raise Exception("blah blah")

 def async_data_processing(self, data_record: Dict) -> Future:
    future = self.executor_pool.submit(self.process_data, data_record)
    return future
```

Now in other class, one of the function is calling `async_data_processing` to perform batch processing/multithreading.

But it seems that the `defaultdict(set)` is creating problems to perform the multithreaded processing smoothly, and every now and then creating KeyError, or would fail to acquire to locks. KeyError doesn't really makes sense, which is the whole point on using defaultdict(set) instead of default dictionary in python.

I have been struggling with this issue for few days and haven't been able to find any proper solution or direction on it.

Reaching out here, in hope of some help!
would appreciate any help, thank you ☺️

Comment: As a side note, the whole point of using a `defaultdict` is so you don't have to do the `if id_value not in self.lock[id_obj.id_key]:` dance.  You just add the value, and the class creates the set if it isn't there.

Comment: ohh! so you mean to say: I can just do ```self.function_thread_lock.acquire()
                        self.lock[id_obj.id_key].add(id_value)
                        break``` ?

Comment: Is this a ThreadPoolExecutor or a ProcessPoolExecutor?  You keep saying threads, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Right!  That's what `defaultdict` does for you.

Comment: it's ThreadPoolExecutor Tim:)

Comment: I don't see a problem here.  Where do you get the KeyError?

Comment: KeyError was certainly at initial stage. Now mostly I am getting error while adding key,value I think. sorry for unclarity but, I am still analyzing some of my logs :(

Comment: I think I am missing something. What is `parameter`?

Comment: ```parameter``` is just a dummy variable which is used in backend to search the specific ids :) @azelcer

Comment: I am sorry, but I would need more information to help. For example, if `obj.get_id_value(data_record)` returns `0` or an empty string no lock is acquired. If you can give more information and clearly state what is the error and where it happens, maybe I can help.